# Can a human being become God and live forever?

Tags: gods, goddess

Can a human being become God and live forever? Have this incident happened before in the history? (a normal being becoming God and stays as God till now)

Answer (score 1):

No, that is NOT possible. Gita says:

> 2.27 For death of anyone born is certain, and of the dead (re-) birth is a certainly. Therefore you ought not to grieve over an inevitable fact.

So no human being who was born can become immortal. Exception proves the rule. In the list of chirajivis, a few are human beings.

And no one can become Ishvara ( God) as God is only ONE. It is not correct to translate God as the Formless All-pervading Brahman, as Adi Shankaracharya says that even the Brahmavid can NOT become Ishvara, Who is the controller of the Universe.

Again, from Gita:

> 18.61 O Arjuna, Isvara resides in the region of the heart of all creatures, revolving through Maya all the creatures (as though) mounted on a machine!

So Isvara is NOT some deathless human being living at a particular place. He is dwelling in each being.

So answers to all your questions is : NO.

Comment: Very good answer @partha

Comment: But the fact is that god resides in every one and everywhere.

Comment: So are Ishwara and Brahman different..If so what is their relation?